# infrequent XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID error when talking with helper app over XPC

Tags: macos, cocoa, xpc

As per Apple's recommendations, we have seperated our root-level functionality of deleting files into a seperate helper app that is installed globally via `SMJobBless()` to `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

At launch our app (UninstallPKG) creates a XPC connection to the helper (`xpc_connection_create_mach_service()`) and when it needs to delete a file it sends a message to the helper app ( `xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync()`) which then performs its task.

This works perfectly well on all our test machines, and for most of our customers. however, it seems like some users are constantly encountering `XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID` failures.
Does anyone have any clue why this happens for some customers and how we could handle or prevent this problem? barring more information about what `XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID` actually means, we currently just quit the app, which is just as bad as a crash.

Google or Apple's documentation or sample code reveals little about under what circumstances `XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID` could be encountered and how it should be gracefully handles. any insights would be appreciated. if Apple is serious about this priviledge separation thing, documentation on how to do so reliably should really be improved.

Btw to a lesser extent we are also seeing `XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED` out in the wild. we are currently just ignoring it. Any insights on this one?

EDIT: FYI in response to our DTS incident spent on this issue Apple has fixed this problem with the release of 10.12. There is no workaround for earlier systems but we have not received any reports of this happening on 10.12+.

Comment: most probably `launchd` is terminating the job for some reason.

Comment: btw, I'm interested to know if your helper process is able to terminate, and if so, does `launchd` automagically restart it ? In my situation, I don't want the helper to keep running, but instead terminate when the job is done. `launchd` seems to ignore launchd-plist keys and unconditionally restart the helper.

Comment: my helper is only launched per demand for each request. i've now spent a DTS incident on this issue and will post the resolution when we find something out.

Comment: So you say your helper exits normally and isn't restarted automatically by `launchd` ? How did you achieve that ?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean XPC helpers are always launched on demand and never 'kept running'

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011-206/

Comment: @user1259710: Did you ever get any resolution to your DTS incident?

Comment: @jamesdlin: apple fixed the issue in 10.12 ... we haven't seen this anymore on uptodate systems